# How to Copy one table data to another table with 2 wherecondtion and an if condtion MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Actually i want to copy one tables data to another table. it has no unique id , the only relation between two are a "fra" number and a 'pra' number but both are not unique . but fra and pra (r concatenate ) is unique for each. and one table data is sex (customer table) and another is gender(new_customer table) the gender is Boolean, sex is string of m and f . how can i copy from customer table to new_customer table
I tried these way

```
  UPDATE new_customer JOIN customer 
SET registrations.name = customer.nam,
registrations.surname = customer.vornam,
registrations.ort = .ort,
registrations.phone = customer.telmbl,
registrations.surname = customer.vornam 
WHERE registrations.fra = customer.fra
 and registrations.pra = customer.pra;
```

Any body to help me?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by *copy*, given that you are showing an `update` statement. Please provide sample data for both tables and expected results so one can try and help.

Comment: Please sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like following, you can try.

```
UPDATE new_customer AS new_c,  customer AS old_c
SET 
  new_c.name = old_c.nam,
  new_c.surname = old_c.vornam,
  new_c.ort = old_c.ort,
  new_c.phone = old_c.telmbl
WHERE 
 new_c.fra = old_c.fra
 AND new_c.pra = old_c.pra;
```

Comment: an error occurred..Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: Some other thread is holding a record lock on some record (because you are updating records in the table)